# how to get program.php from localhost/xxx/index.php?path=program.php?op=xx?

Tags: php, get, split, directory

I dont know what to search this time, and i dont know if its even possible, so thats why i try to ask here.

I want to know if its possible to get the program.php without the get parameters from localhost/xxx/index.php?path=program.php?op=xx

especially in this case, i need folder/program.php from this string

localhost/xxx/index.php?path=folder/program.php?op=xx

The thing is, im updating and old and big application but i dont want to http include or something, so i have to get the thing i need to include, and also the parameters of the path (in thix examphe the value of "op"), but i dont know how.. maybe someone had this problem before? is it even possible?

greetings

Comment: Is it coming up with URL or as string input?

Comment: its URL but i can get the "path" with everything that comes after from the url, but then i would still need to split up.. the problem is, how it is now i would have to edit every single link because of the other GET parameters and turn ? to & i would like to save that time, because its a lot of other work to do.. but i still didnt find a solution for it myself :(

Comment: localhost/xxx/index.php?path=program.php?op=xx  -- the url should be localhost/xxx/index.php?path=program.php&op=xx -- change in &op=xx and if you cant do it please user $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to get the values and then use explode to get into it. If you need any help on that, please ask me again.

Comment: Hello, thank you, QUERY_STRING works for me, =)